# How does INA 290 reduce voltage level from 120V to ICMR range of the corresponding op-amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, common-mode

How 120 V is in the Input Common Mode Range of the op-amps?

Comment: Please link (in the question) the data sheet for the device you mention. The device is not an op-amp BTW.

Comment: The manufacturer's data sheet gives all the information needed, with schematics and details. _"The INAx290 is designed using a transconductance architecture with a current-feedback amplifier that enables low bias currents of 20 μA and a common-mode voltage of 120 V"_, [See TI docs](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina290.pdf)

Comment: @LuC this comment would make a great answer

Comment: @Luc But I didn't understand and find the internal architecture of current feedback amplifier.

Comment: @Andyaka https://www.ti.com.cn/lit/ds/symlink/ina293.pdf?ts=1690192394901&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.bing.com%252F

Answer (score 0):

> *How does INA 290 reduce voltage level from 120V to ICMR range of the
> corresponding op-amp?*

Basically, a low-gain differential amplifier type configuration can be used. I'm not saying that the IN290 doesn't do a few other tricks of course. Anyway, a [differential amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_amplifier) is like this: -

[image]

And we usually make Rf = Rg and R1 = R2. But, if we make R1 and R2 fifty times bigger that Rf and Rg, we create an attenuating differential amplifier. In these circumstances, with a common mode voltage of 120 volts on V1 and V2, the voltage seen at the inputs to the op-amp will be about 2.35 volts and fully within the actual input range for the op-amp if it is powered from 5 volts.

So, the above is a method of using a 5 volt powered op-amp to measure differential signals that have a high common-mode voltage and, like I said earlier, I'm sure TI will do some other tricks to make this work effectively.

Comment: Hey Andy, I flagged this post to follow, because I was interested to know such "tricks". Any hints as to what kind of magic tricks they might use? I have a hard time believing they'd divide by fifty, just to multiply by fifty again!

Comment: @SimonFitch they probably float the op-amp up to the 120 volt rail and have some kind of zener regulator to give it a local 0 volts that's 5 volts below the 120 volts. But really, I'm guessing.

Comment: Hey @Andyaka, I use voltage divider to reduction the voltage like 70 to 3.85V to match the ICMR with all transistors are in saturation region. Is it a good idea?

Comment: @K.M.SayemBinRahmotullah If you need to get an answer to this comment you should raise a new question so, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind TI's high-side current sense amplifiers can be clearly seen in their application notes, about the first parts that they released - many named INA1xx in their current sensing portfolio.

Take as an example [INA168](https://www.ti.com/product/INA168), which has many good references in its *Technical documentation* section on site.

A good introductory document is [High-voltage, high-side floating current sensing circuit using current output, current sense amplifier](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sboa295/sboa295.pdf) loaded with simulation data and additional original resources listed.

As an example there's a reference to their *Design resources*, as the very similar [high side sensing circuit](https://www.ti.com/tool/CIRCUIT060032).